# Excel return true or false if the value is found in another sheet

Tags: excel

I want to return a True or False depending on if a value is found in another sheet.  The problem I am encountering is that if the value is found on the other sheet it usually pops up mutiple times.  This is making the vlookup return #N/A when I do set it to an exact match.

Comment: Please update your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

A repeated value will not produce `#N/A` error as it will simply produce the first match it encounters. This likely means that it is not finding a match. If you can see the values clearly it might mean that they are in a different format (ie text rather than value or vice versa). Check how the values are stored for each piece and make sure data types are the same. A good trick to check how it views each value is to use the `Evaluate Formula` feature to step through each calculation.